# How to disable the new copy/paste protection in XFCE?

Tags: copy-paste, xfce

My desktop environment/window manager (XFCE) in Debian has sadly, suddenly started asking me if I'm sure I want to copy/paste into my terminal.

Yes. I'm sure, always.

How do I disable this fantastical technology, with XFCE specifically? Debian 9.9, if it matters.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is new "feature" of xfce4-terminal.

Go to Edit > Preferences > General tab and uncheck "Show unsafe paste dialog".

Comment: It looks like the unsafe past dialog was just implemented in Xfce Terminal v0.8.8, which was very recently released.

Comment: Well, I hope it got the "retarded feature of the year" award.

Answer (score 1):

[Another answer](https://superuser.com/a/1469352/332907) here explains how to handle this issue through the GUI. However, if you need to do it in a script or from the terminal itself:

```
echo "MiscShowUnsafePasteDialog=FALSE" | sudo tee -a /etc/xdg/xdg-backbox/xfce4/terminal/terminalrc
```

Comment: Your approach changes the system-wide settings. Perhaps it would be better to show how to change the setting within the user's account (like the other answer does, but through the GUI)

Comment: I tried the user-specific location in a test machine:
/home/%USER/.config/xfce4/terminal/terminalrc
with mixed results.

Comment: Mixed results maybe because `%USER` isn't a valid value? You could try `sed -i '/^MiscShowUnsafePasteDialog/s/=.*/=FALSE/' "${XDG_CONFIG_HOME:-$HOME/.config}/xfce4/terminal/terminalrc"`, which will update the `MiscShowUnsafePasteDialog` value. Unfortunately it won't create it if the entry is missing, and I don't have a copy of the `terminalrc` with which I can test a foolproof suggestion

Comment: I mistyped the % instead of $.
The issue is that the terminalrc doesn't seem to be copied to the user's profile automatically. I think it is generated when there are changes made in the GUI. I haven't been able to test just copying the /etc/xdg/xdg-backbox/xfce4/terminal/terminalrc to the profile location and making changes there. For my purposes, a global change is acceptable, and it took forever to come up with this solution. I figured I'd put it here for the next person googling to try and find the answer.

Comment: Sounds good to me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It is year 2022 now and the Edit > Preferences > General (tab) > "Show unsafe paste dialog" is no longer present.

However, Edit > Preferences > Advanced (tab) has checkboxes related to copy & paste via mouse, for those of us missing the old X-Window/XTerm/PuTTY behavior:

1. Use middle mouse click to close tabs
2. Use middle mouse click to open URL
3. Automatically copy selection to clipboard.

[Terminal Preferences (Advanced tab)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BEfY3.png)